# jgrapht KruskalMinimumSpanningTree retrieving the edge weights

Tags: java, jgrapht

I have a graph and I need to get the **minimum spanning tree** so I used `KruskalMinimumSpanningTree` class, now I need to retrieve each edge weight so according to the API of [DefaultWeightedEdge](http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/graph/DefaultWeightedEdge.html) there's a method `getWeight()`
which retrieves the weight of an edge, However after implementing the following code the method `getWeight()` doesn't exist!

```
     KruskalMinimumSpanningTree<Pixel, DefaultWeightedEdge> k= new KruskalMinimumSpanningTree(gg);
         Set<DefaultWeightedEdge> itr = k.getSpanningTree().getEdges();
         for(DefaultWeightedEdge edge: itr)
             System.out.println(edge.getWeight());
```

why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. i found a solution for my question, apparently these methods are protected. one way of doing it is:

```
   KruskalMinimumSpanningTree<Pixel, DefaultWeightedEdge> k= new 
    KruskalMinimumSpanningTree(gg);
         Set<DefaultWeightedEdge> itr = k.getSpanningTree().getEdges();
         for(DefaultWeightedEdge edge: itr)
             System.out.println(gg.getEdgeWeight(edge));
```

Comment: This is the correct (and intended) way to do it. You are expected to query the weight of an edge through the Graph interface.